# Construct pandas DataFrame from list of tuples of (row,col,values)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pivot

I have a list of tuples like

```
data = [
('r1', 'c1', avg11, stdev11),
('r1', 'c2', avg12, stdev12),
('r2', 'c1', avg21, stdev21),
('r2', 'c2', avg22, stdev22)
]
```

and I would like to put them into a pandas DataFrame with rows named by the first column and columns named by the 2nd column. It seems the way to take care of the row names is something like `pandas.DataFrame([x[1:] for x in data], index = [x[0] for x in data])` but how do I take care of the columns to get a 2x2 matrix (the output from the previous set is 3x4)? Is there a more intelligent way of taking care of row labels as well, instead of explicitly omitting them?

**EDIT** It seems I will need 2 DataFrames - one for averages and one for standard deviations, is that correct? Or can I store a list of values in each "cell"?

Comment: Definite duplicate of < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415701/efficiently-construct-pandas-dataframe-from-large-list-of-tuples-rows?rq=1 >

Comment: @EMS not at all. I saw that question, he did not need the 2D pivoting.

Comment: @ely, gt6989b I retitled this "...from list of tuples of (row,col,values)" to make it clear why this is **not a duplicate** of "...from tuples"

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200157/list-of-tuples-to-dataframe-conversion

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can pivot your DataFrame after creating:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.pivot(index=0, columns=1, values=2)
# avg DataFrame
1      c1     c2
0               
r1  avg11  avg12
r2  avg21  avg22
>>> df.pivot(index=0, columns=1, values=3)
# stdev DataFrame
1        c1       c2
0                   
r1  stdev11  stdev12
r2  stdev21  stdev22
```

Comment: The row with index `0` and column with name `1` aren't very beautiful...

Answer (score 51):

I submit that it is better to leave your data stacked as it is:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['R_Number', 'C_Number', 'Avg', 'Std'])

# Possibly also this if these can always be the indexes:
# df = df.set_index(['R_Number', 'C_Number'])
```

Then it's a bit more intuitive to say

```
df.set_index(['R_Number', 'C_Number']).Avg.unstack(level=1)
```

This way it is implicit that you're seeking to reshape the averages, or the standard deviations. Whereas, just using `pivot`, it's purely based on column convention as to what semantic entity it is that you are reshaping.

Comment: +1, useful explicitness. I am explicitly interested in a 2D table -- to allow me to search for values, indexed by both row- and column- lists, as well as access each of the dimensions separately. Can you do that with stacked data?

Comment: Yep. Much better with stacked data. Think of a relational database table, like in SQL. You don't go blowing out a whole column into a bunch of repeated columns do you? That should only happen in special cases (I think it is the tall-to-wide pattern). Normally, you treat multiple columns as indexes, and make selections by partially binding one of the index columns, or binding them all to get a specific record.

Comment: So, in your case, after setting the index to be `[R_Number, C_Number]` you can do `df.ix[('r1','c2')]`, for example. Or you can leave those both as regular columns and use logical indexing: `df[(df.R_Number == 'r1') & (df.C_Number == 'c2')]`

Answer (score 37):

This is what I expected to see when I came to this question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3, 4),
                   (5, 6, 7, 8),
                   (9, 0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5, 6)],
                  columns=list('abcd'),
                  index=['India', 'France', 'England', 'Germany'])
print(df)
```

gives

```
         a  b  c  d
India    1  2  3  4
France   5  6  7  8
England  9  0  1  2
Germany  3  4  5  6
```

Comment: You misread the question. The data originally given in the question already has row and column labels for each record in question.

Comment: @gt6989b No, I didn't. I didn't try to answer the original question, but the question people (might) have when they come to this page.

Comment: @MartinThoma Thanks, indeed this is what I am looking for on this page.

Comment: Indeed I was expecting this too