# How do I find the neighbors of points containing coordinates in Python?

Tags: python, coordinates, wgs84

I have lots of points with their coordinates. 
I want to print **at least the three closest neighbors of one point and their distance to that point**. How can I do that in Python? In WGS84 system.

```
NAME    Latitude    Longitude
B   50.94029883 7.019146728
C   50.92073002 6.975268711
D   50.99807758 6.980865543
E   50.98074288 7.035060206
F   51.00696972 7.035993783
G   50.97369889 6.928538763
H   50.94133859 6.927878587
A   50.96712502 6.977825322
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearest neighbor techniques more efficient for lots of points

- Brute force (i.e. looping over all the points) complexity is O(N^2)
- Nearest neighbor algorithms complexity is O(N*log(N))

Nearest Neighbor in Python

1. [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html)
2. [KdTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html)
3. [Explaining Nearest Neighbor](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse547/17sp/slides/kNN-kdtrees-2.pdf)
4. [BallTree vs. KdTree Performance](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/04/29/benchmarking-nearest-neighbor-searches-in-python/)

Illustration of using BallTree on your problem (related [Related Stackoverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924460/finding-similar-entries-in-python-lists/61924949?noredirect=1#comment109527047_61924949))

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
from io import StringIO

# Create DataFrame from you lat/lon dataset
data = """NAME Latitude Longitude
B 50.94029883 7.019146728
C 50.92073002 6.975268711
D 50.99807758 6.980865543
E 50.98074288 7.035060206
F 51.00696972 7.035993783
G 50.97369889 6.928538763
H 50.94133859 6.927878587
A 50.96712502 6.977825322"""

# Use StringIO to allow reading of string as CSV
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep = ' ')

# Setup Balltree using df as reference dataset
# Use Haversine calculate distance between points on the earth from lat/long
# haversine - https://pypi.org/project/haversine/ 
tree = BallTree(np.deg2rad(df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].values), metric='haversine')

# Setup distance queries (points for which we want to find nearest neighbors)
other_data = """NAME Latitude Longitude
B_alt 50.94029883 7.019146728
C_alt 50.92073002 6.975268711"""

df_other = pd.read_csv(StringIO(other_data), sep = ' ')

query_lats = df_other['Latitude']
query_lons = df_other['Longitude']

# Find closest city in reference dataset for each in df_other
# use k = 3 for 3 closest neighbors
distances, indices = tree.query(np.deg2rad(np.c_[query_lats, query_lons]), k = 3)

r_km = 6371 # multiplier to convert to km (from unit distance)
for name, d, ind in zip(df_other['NAME'], distances, indices):
  print(f"NAME {name} closest matches:")
  for i, index in enumerate(ind):
    print(f"\t{df['NAME'][index]} with distance {d[i]*r_km:.4f} km")
```

**Output**

```
NAME B_alt closest matches:
    B with distance 0.0000 km
    C with distance 3.7671 km
    A with distance 4.1564 km
NAME C_alt closest matches:
    C with distance 0.0000 km
    B with distance 3.7671 km
    H with distance 4.0350 km
```