# Compute Euclidian distance in 100 dimensions between many points: how to be fast?

Tags: python, dataframe, euclidean-distance, euclidean-algorithm

- I have a Pandas DataFrame of 2 million entries
- Each entry is a point in a 100 dimensional space

[image]

- I want to compute the Euclidian distance between the N last points and all the others to find the closest neighbors (to simplify let's say find the top#1 closest neighbor for the 5 last points)
- **I have done the code below for a small dataset, but it's fairly slow, and I'm looking for ideas of improvement (especially speed improvement!)**

The logic is the following:

- Split the dataframe between **target** for which we want to find the closest neighbor and
  **compare** : all others among which we will look for the neighbor
- Iterate through the targets
- Compute the Squared Euclidean distance of each df_compare point VS the target
- Select the top#1 value of the compare df and save its ID in the target dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Name': ['Ly','Gr','Er','Ca','Cy','Sc','Cr','Cn','Le','Cs','An','Ta','Sa','Ly','Az','Sx','Ud','Lr','Si','Au','Co','Ck','Mj','wa'],
        'dim0': [33,-9,18,-50,39,-23,-19,89,-74,81,8,23,-63,-62,-14,45,39,-46,74,19,7,97,-29,71,],
        'dim1': [-7,75,77,-93,-89,4,-96,-64,41,-27,-87,23,-69,-77,-92,18,21,27,-76,-57,-44,20,15,-76,],
        'dim2': [-31,54,-14,-93,72,-14,65,44,-88,19,48,-51,-25,36,-46,98,8,0,53,-47,-29,95,65,-3,],
        'dim3': [-12,-86,10,93,-79,-55,-6,-79,-12,66,-81,-14,44,84,9,-19,-69,29,-50,-59,35,-28,90,-73,],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_target = df.tail(5)
df_target['closest_neighbour'] = np.nan
df_compare= df.drop(df.tail(5).index)

for i, target_row in df_target.iterrows():  
    df_compare['distance'] = 0
    for dim in df_target.columns:
        if dim.startswith('dim'):
            df_compare['distance'] = df_compare['distance'] + (target_row[dim] - df_compare[dim])**2

    df_compare.sort_values(by=['distance'], ascending=True, inplace=True)
    closest_neighbor=df_compare.head(1)
    df_target.loc[df_target.index==i,'closest_neighbour']= closest_neighbor['Name'].iloc[0]

print(df_target)
```

Any suggestion of improvement of the logic or the code is welcome!
Cheers

Comment: It seems like computing the euclidean distance is only used to find the nearest neighbor. Use for example https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html instead?

Comment: Although the doc says it is better for dimensions < 20, Paul's suggestion is a very interesting one!

Answer (score 3):

Constructing the dataframe with `drop_duplicates('Name')` because I find that at least `Ly` appears twice.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Name': ['Ly','Gr','Er','Ca','Cy','Sc','Cr','Cn','Le','Cs','An','Ta','Sa','Ly','Az','Sx','Ud','Lr','Si','Au','Co','Ck','Mj','wa'],
        'dim0': [33,-9,18,-50,39,-23,-19,89,-74,81,8,23,-63,-62,-14,45,39,-46,74,19,7,97,-29,71,],
        'dim1': [-7,75,77,-93,-89,4,-96,-64,41,-27,-87,23,-69,-77,-92,18,21,27,-76,-57,-44,20,15,-76,],
        'dim2': [-31,54,-14,-93,72,-14,65,44,-88,19,48,-51,-25,36,-46,98,8,0,53,-47,-29,95,65,-3,],
        'dim3': [-12,-86,10,93,-79,-55,-6,-79,-12,66,-81,-14,44,84,9,-19,-69,29,-50,-59,35,-28,90,-73,],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data).drop_duplicates('Name')

df_target = df.tail(5)
df_compare= df.drop(df.tail(5).index)
```

One way is to `apply` a row-wise operation

```
df_target = df_target.set_index('Name')
df_compare = df_compare.set_index('Name')

df_compare.apply(lambda r: ((r - df_target)**2).sum(axis=1), axis=1).idxmin()
```

Outcome:

```
Name
Au    Ly
Co    Az
Ck    Sx
Mj    Lr
wa    Cn
dtype: object
```

Another, which is my preference, is to do it in numpy array:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    ((df_target.values[:, np.newaxis] - df_compare.values)**2).sum(axis=2),
    columns = df_compare.index,
    index = df_target.index,
).idxmin(axis=1)
```

which will yield the same outcome

Comment: Maybe, to save some more seconds, one could use `np.linalg.norm(vector1 - vector2)` instead of manually computing the distance.

Answer (score 2):

If you get numpy arrays out of the data frame, you can compute them using Numba fast:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import jit

import math
import numpy as np

data = {'Name': [""]*1000,
        'dim0': [0]*1000,
        'dim1': [0]*1000,
        'dim2': [0]*1000,
        'dim3': [0]*1000,
        }

# add rest of dims
for i in range(96):
    data["dim"+str(i+4)]=[0]*1000

dims=len(data)-1
N=len(data["Name"])
print(dims)
print(N)


def distance(selected,selected2):
    dif=selected-selected2
    dif*=dif
    dist=0.0
    for val in dif:
        dist += val
    return math.sqrt(dist)

@jit(nopython=True)
def distanceNumba(selected,selected2):
    dif=selected-selected2
    dif*=dif
    dist=0.0
    for val in dif:
        dist += val
    return math.sqrt(dist)

cache=[];

for i in range(N):
    cache.append(np.zeros(dims))

cache=np.asarray(cache)

for i in range(dims):
    for j in range(N):
        cache[j][i]=data["dim"+str(i)][j]

selected=cache[0]

out = np.zeros(N)


def distances(selected,cache,out):
    i=0
    for selected2 in cache:
        out[i]=distance(selected,selected2)
        i=i+1

@jit(nopython=True)
def distancesNumba(selected,cache,out):
    i=0
    for selected2 in cache:
        out[i]=distanceNumba(selected,selected2)
        i=i+1

for i in range(10):
    t1 = timer()
    distances(selected,cache,out)
    t2 = timer()
    print(t2-t1," seconds without numba")

    t1 = timer()
    distancesNumba(selected,cache,out)
    t2 = timer()
    print(t2-t1," seconds with numba")

print(out)
```

output:

```
100
1000
0.05954742600079044  seconds without numba
1.2770428250005352  seconds with numba
0.0608673019996786  seconds without numba
0.0009444430033909157  seconds with numba
0.060780961997807026  seconds without numba
0.0009288470027968287  seconds with numba
0.06079873300041072  seconds without numba
0.0009262589992431458  seconds with numba
0.06075674100065953  seconds without numba
0.0009228080016328022  seconds with numba
0.06063023499882547  seconds without numba
0.0009203600020555314  seconds with numba
0.0607308569997258  seconds without numba
0.0009688009995443281  seconds with numba
0.06056219499805593  seconds without numba
0.000959154000156559  seconds with numba
0.060522257001139224  seconds without numba
0.0009322579971922096  seconds with numba
0.06055161300173495  seconds without numba
0.000933799001359148  seconds with numba
```

If you have CUDA graphics card, then you can use it too:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

from numba import jit
from numba import cuda
import numba
import math
import numpy as np

data = {'Name': [""]*1000,
        'dim0': [0]*1000,
        'dim1': [0]*1000,
        'dim2': [0]*1000,
        'dim3': [0]*1000,
        }

# add rest of dims
for i in range(96):
    data["dim"+str(i+4)]=[0]*1000

dims=len(data)-1
N=len(data["Name"])
print(dims)
print(N)


def distance(selected,selected2):
    dif=selected-selected2
    dif*=dif
    dist=0.0
    for val in dif:
        dist += val
    return math.sqrt(dist)

cache=[];

for i in range(N):
    cache.append(np.zeros(dims))

cache=np.asarray(cache,dtype=np.float32)

for i in range(dims):
    for j in range(N):
        cache[j][i]=data["dim"+str(i)][j]

selected=cache[0]

out = np.zeros(N)


def distances(selected,cache,out):
    i=0
    for selected2 in cache:
        out[i]=distance(selected,selected2)
        i=i+1

@cuda.jit
def distancesNumba(selected,cache,out):
    i=0
    for selected2 in cache:
        dif=cuda.local.array(shape=dims, dtype=numba.float32) 
        dif[cuda.threadIdx.x]=selected[cuda.threadIdx.x]-selected2[cuda.threadIdx.x]
        dif[cuda.threadIdx.x]*=dif[cuda.threadIdx.x]
        dist=0.0
        numba.cuda.syncthreads()
        if cuda.threadIdx.x==0:
            for j in range(dims):
                dist += dif[j]
            out[i]=math.sqrt(dist)
            i=i+1
        
        

for i in range(10):
    t1 = timer()
    distances(selected,cache,out)
    t2 = timer()
    print(t2-t1," seconds without numba")

    t1 = timer()
    # 1=blocks, 100=threads
    distancesNumba[1,100](selected,cache,out)
    t2 = timer()
    print(t2-t1," seconds with numba")

print(out)
```

output:

```
100
1000
0.09203408300163574  seconds without numba
1.3188036539977475  seconds with numba
0.09138548299961258  seconds without numba
0.00905935400078306  seconds with numba
0.09278915700269863  seconds without numba
0.011017041997547494  seconds with numba
0.09266194800147787  seconds without numba
0.009332213001471246  seconds with numba
0.09425603599811438  seconds without numba
0.008965768000052776  seconds with numba
0.09545346899903961  seconds without numba
0.009094572000321932  seconds with numba
0.09400588900098228  seconds without numba
0.008994818999781273  seconds with numba
0.09595919099956518  seconds without numba
0.009412939001776977  seconds with numba
0.09670166400246671  seconds without numba
0.009072380998986773  seconds with numba
0.09463289600171265  seconds without numba
0.009022546000778675  seconds with numba
```

this performance is only by 100 CUDA threads and without reduction optimization for the distance (simply adds 100 values by 1 cuda thread after the squared differences are computed). You can adjust number of threads for kernel, optimize with reduction for distance summation and get higher performance.

Then you can simply sort the "out" array to get the shortest/longest distances.

Edit: optimization for more CUDA threads (1 block per line, dims threads per block) + reduction in kernel

```
@cuda.jit
def distancesNumba(selected,cache,out):
    i=0
    selected2=cuda.blockIdx.x
    dif=cuda.local.array(shape=dims, dtype=numba.float32) 
    dif[cuda.threadIdx.x]=selected[cuda.threadIdx.x]-cache[selected2][cuda.threadIdx.x]
    dif[cuda.threadIdx.x]*=dif[cuda.threadIdx.x]
    dist=0.0
    numba.cuda.syncthreads()

    reduction=128
    while reduction>0:
        if reduction+cuda.threadIdx.x < dims:
            dif[reduction] += dif[reduction+cuda.threadIdx.x]
        numba.cuda.syncthreads()
        reduction>>=2
    if cuda.threadIdx.x==0:
        out[selected2]=math.sqrt(dif[0])
```

and launching it with:

```
# compute distances of selected line to N lines (dims dimensional)
distancesNumba[N,dims](selected,cache,out)
```

performance becomes:

```
100 <-- dimensions
100000 <-- N
8.610873253001046  seconds without numba
1.8519197440000426  seconds with numba
8.927837033999822  seconds without numba
0.20861789699847577  seconds with numba
8.859914688000572  seconds without numba
0.20821334699940053  seconds with numba
8.980341544000112  seconds without numba
0.21734917999856407  seconds with numba
8.818792854999629  seconds without numba
0.22718691900081467  seconds with numba
9.003342153999256  seconds without numba
0.2289118230000895  seconds with numba
9.02532176999739  seconds without numba
0.20479743699979736  seconds with numba
8.9248614370008  seconds without numba
0.21945642799983034  seconds with numba
```

For 1 million lines and 100 dimensions:

```
100
1000000
81.72404483399805  seconds without numba
8.821669873999781  seconds with numba
86.97093956900062  seconds without numba
2.0208445850003045  seconds with numba
84.32691005200104  seconds without numba
2.0129999929995392  seconds with numba
```

it's only 40x performance because it is making only single distance check against all lines. Adding 4-5 more distances to check per line would be more efficient. You can also do "tiling" optimization to use L1 cache of GPU for even higher performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe stores the columns as `numpy` arrays. But for your calculations, it would probably be more efficient to have the dim*n* *rows* as numpy arrays, because the distance calculation could then leverage `numpy` array operations.

Answer (score 1):

**More Effienet Algorithm**

Rather than using Brute Force, you can use [Tree Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952561/how-do-i-find-the-neighbors-of-points-containing-coordinates-in-python/61953744#61953744)

Advantages of Tree Methods (e.g. BallTree, KDTree, etc.)

For N points in Target and Compare

- Brute Force complexity is N*N
- Tree Methods complexity is N*log(N)
- This makes Tree methods significant faster than Brute Force for large N (e.g. 2M)

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

# Data
df_target = df.tail(5)
df_compare= df.drop(df.tail(5).index)

# Create Distance Tree with Euclidean distance metric  (skipping Name column)
tree = BallTree(df_compare[df_compare.columns[1:]].values, metric = "euclidean")

# Find nearest neighbor for each node in target (skipping Name column)
distances, indices = tree.query(df_target[df_target.columns[1:]].values, k = 1)

# Show closest name in compare for each name in target
for target, compare in zip(df_target['Name'], df_compare.iloc[indices.flatten()]['Name']):
    print(f"{target}  {compare}")
```

**Output**

```
Au  Ly
Co  Az
Ck  Sx
Mj  Lr
wa  Cn
```