# Extracting column from dataframe based on matching three column values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes :

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns={'Date', 'latitude' , 'longitude' , 'tg'})

df1.head(5).to_dict() : 

{'Date': {0: Timestamp('1984-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('1984-01-02 
00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('1984-01-03 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('1984-01-04 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('1984-01-05 00:00:00')}, 'longitude': {0: 13.875,
 1: 13.875, 2: 13.875, 3: 13.875, 4: 13.875}, 'tg': {0: 5.339999675750732, 
1: 2.559999942779541, 2: 4.019999980926514, 3: -0.07000000029802322, 4: 
-2.259999990463257}, 'latitude': {0: 49.125, 1: 49.125, 2: 49.125, 3: 
49.125, 4: 49.125}}



df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns={'Date', 'latitude_rr' , 'longitude_rr' , 'Runoff' , 'rr'})

df2.head(5).to_dict() : 

{'Date': {0: Timestamp('1984-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('1984-01-02 
00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('1984-01-03 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('1984-01-04 
00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('1984-01-05 00:00:00')}, 'latitude_rr': {0: 49.125, 
1: 49.125, 2: 49.125, 3: 49.125, 4: 49.125}, 'longitude_rr': {0: 13.875, 1: 
13.875, 2: 13.875, 3: 13.875, 4: 13.875}, 'Runoff': {0: 0.3808451, 1: 
0.3808451, 2: 0.6760563, 3: 1.464789, 4: 2.456338}, 'rr': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 
2: 2.799999952316284, 3: 2.200000047683716, 4: 0.4000000059604645}}
```

I am trying to get the **'tg'** values when df1.Date equals df2.Date and df1.latitude equals df2.latitude and df1.longitude equals df2.longitude then add them to **df2**.

df1 and df2 don't have the same size. I tried :

```
df3 = df1[df1.latitude.isin(df2.latitude_rr) & df1.longitude.isin(df2.longitude_rr) & df1.Date.isin(df2.Date)].tg
```

I tried to add that to df2 but since df2 is larger than df1 , it leads to wrong matches.

I am new to Pandas so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If they are not the same size, what unique identification do you have in order to compare them? Is there an `id` field that two dataframes can be compared based on?

Comment: The unique identifications would be the date , longitude and latitude.

Comment: @ansev. It's not so simple as merge here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's sufficient, use `df.merge`:

```
out = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'latitude_rr': 'latitude', 
                                    'longitude_rr': 'longitude'}),
                on=['Date', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
print(out)

# Output
        Date  longitude    tg  latitude    Runoff   rr
0 1984-01-01     13.875  5.34    49.125  0.380845  0.0
1 1984-01-02     13.875  2.56    49.125  0.380845  0.0
2 1984-01-03     13.875  4.02    49.125  0.676056  2.8
3 1984-01-04     13.875 -0.07    49.125  1.464789  2.2
4 1984-01-05     13.875 -2.26    49.125  2.456338  0.4
```

If it's not sufficient, you can use [`KDTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67134845/15239951) can help you.

---

First merge your 2 dataframes only by `date` because it's not a good choice to merge on `latitude` and `longitude` (float precision). You need a function like [`np.close`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to match coordinates:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on='Date')

m1 = np.isclose(out['latitude'], out['latitude_rr'], atol=0.00001)
m2 = np.isclose(out['longitude'], out['longitude_rr'], atol=0.00001)
out = out[m1 & m2]
```

You have to adjust the tolerance `atol`

Comment: I have the same date sequence for different latitudes and longitudes. I get a MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.93 GiB for an array with shape (259324578,) and data type int64 when trying to merge.

Comment: Please update your post with a significant sample. `print(df1.head(5).to_dict())` and `print(df2.head(5).to_dict())`

Comment: Maybe you should use `KDTree`. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67134845/15239951

Comment: Post updated! I'll have a look at KDTree.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?