# The easiest way to read an Access table with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I have an access database name DB_IMPORT_2020.accdb. It contains only one table named DB_IMPORT_2020_PM. I've been struggling a lot trying to import that table to Pandas.
What I've been doing so far is:

```
# define components of our connection string
driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}'
filepath = r"C:\Users\corra\Desktop\DB_IMPORT_2020.accdb"

# create a connection to the database
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver = driver, dbq = filepath, autocommit = True)

crsr = cnxn.cursor()

# define the components of a query
table_name = 'DB_IMPORT_2020_PM'

# define query

query = "SELECT * FROM {}".format(table_name)

# execute the query

crsr.execute(query)

data = crsr.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then I come to the situation where I have a pandas dataframe with a single column and a list in each row.

```
0
________________________________________________________
0   [86232, 2019-09-12, INTERNET, ... , N ]
1   [86233, 2019-09-12, INTERNET, ... , M ]
2   [86234, 2019-09-12, MEZZO LIBERO, ...  , Q ]
3   ...
```

I feel like this is not the right way to do it and it is overly complicated.
Does anyone know a simpler way to read data in a table of Access with Pandas?

This is the list i get with data = crsr.fetchall()

```
[(86232, datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 12, 0, 0), 'INTERNET', 'A.M Web', 'Brand_SMX', 0.0, 'gen', '20_FCST', 'OnLine', 'dipendente s', 'Low Rev.', 'STX', 'A.M', 'INTERNET', 'Brand_SMX', 'dipendente s', 'STORICI', 'TIER 1', 1.0, 'TIER 1', 'ALIMENTARI', '04_SRF', 'SMX', 'ALTRI', 'STC', 'Reservation', 'Off + On', 'Online_Res', 'TIER 1', None, None, None, None),
 (86233, datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 12, 0, 0), 'INTERNET', 'A.M Web', 'Brand_SMX', 0.0, 'feb', '20_FCST', 'OnLine', 'dipendente s', 'Low Rev.', 'STC', 'A. M', 'INTERNET', 'Brand_SMX', 'dipendente s', 'STORICI', 'TIER 1', 1.0, 'TIER 1', 'ALIMENTARI', '04_SRF', 'SMX', 'ALTRI', 'STX', 'Reservation', 'Off + On', 'Online_Res', 'TIER 1', None, None, None, None),
 (86234, datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 12, 0, 0), 'MEZZO LIBERO', 'S ITALIA SRL', 'S ELECTRONICS', 0.0, 'gen', '20_FCST', 'OffLine', 'BO / CI', 'Low Rev.', 'STX', 'S Italia Srl', 'MEZZO LIBERO', 'S', 'BEN BOT', 'STORICI', 'INTERCx', 1.0, 'INTERCx', 'INFORMATICA/FOTOGRAFIA', '04_SRF', 'SMX', 'ALTRI', 'STC', 'Reservation', 'Off + On', 'Offline_Res', 'INTX', None, None, None, None),...]
```

Comment: what type is `data = crsr.fetchall()`?

Comment: the type is list

Comment: I think maybe `df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])` could do the trick. Otherwise can you add a print of `data`?

Comment: No it doesn't work, I have added the first two lines of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to work with an Access database and pandas is to use the [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) dialect (which I maintain).

> Does anyone know a simpler way to read data in a table of Access with Pandas?

Just use pandas' [read_sql_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_table.html) method:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

table_name = 'DB_IMPORT_2020_PM'

engine = sa.create_engine("access+pyodbc://@my_accdb_dsn")
df = pd.read_sql_table(table_name, engine)
```

Comment: You might want to disclose affiliation in this answer and add some more content (a quick example of how to use it), as per [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Still a good answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a `list` of `tuples`, you need to add the columns when creating the dataframe as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200157/list-of-tuples-to-dataframe-conversion):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ["col1","col2",...,"coln"])
```

Comment: I get this error ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1914390, 1), indices imply (1914390, 33) . I have 33 columns and added df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10","col11","col12","col13","col14","col15","col16","col17","col18","col19","col20","col21","col22","col23","col24","col25","col26","col27","col28","col29","col30","col31","col32","col33"])

Comment: If i change to df = pd.DataFrame([data],columns = ["col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10","col11","col12","col13","col14","col15","col16","col17","col18","col19","col20","col21","col22","col23","col24","col25","col26","col27","col28","col29","col30","col31","col32","col33"])
 i get this error: ValueError: 33 columns passed, passed data had 1914390 columns

Comment: Actually, I have tried to do `pd.DataFrame(data)` and it works with the sample data you provided. What error do you obtain with `df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])`? Do you have any field with `'` or `"` and commas inside or something like that? Otherwise don't really know what's happening.